# Webpack slow CSS rebuilds with image deps

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm requiring https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/blob/master/css/flag-icon.css in my build.

`css
@import url("~flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css");`

flag-icons is a CSS which requires many flag images.

The build time is quite slow, 300ms on rebuild for watch. Using webpack-dev-server instead of webpack + watch makes no difference. I make all image files 0 bytes, almost no difference too.

I wonder, what's the reason? Any way to speedup?

Comment: Could you show us an example project or your webpack configuration? It's hard to answer the question without a sample. First guess: Are you inlining all flag images? Also checkout this issue with css-loader: https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/124

Comment: 300ms! Give me a break. Mine takes 2000ms+, and I don't think it has anything to do with images.